# JMeter: In jp@gc Webdriver Sampler, how to launch the chrome browser in incognito mode

Tags: jmeter, incognito-mode

Using  jp@gc Webdriver Sampler, I am trying to get the Microsoft AD user oauth2.0 authorization code. I need to launch the browser in incognito mode in order make sure that is does not use my SSO instead uses test user login. How do I launch the browser in incognito mode?

I tried to add options 'ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();  options.addArguments("incognito");' under additional arguments in options tab of chrome driver congig

Answer (score 0):

You need to just provide `--incognito` to "Additional arguments" input [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wj9du.png)

When it comes to the overall approach I don't think using a real browser is a good solution, you should be able to bypass OAuth2 authentication using "normal" JMeter [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers, it should be a matter of a simple (or not very simple) [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter)

You can take a look at [atlassian-microsoft-oauth.jmx](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/oauth2-correlation/src/master/atlassian-microsoft-oauth.jmx) example test plan to see how it can be done.